# SMS One tap verification SMS activity restarts after click on "allow"

Tags: android, kotlin, sms

I'm currently using One tap verification SMS and when I clicked the allow button, the app restarts for no reason, I followed the documentation tutorial(https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/user-consent/request) exactly, but it still happens

Edit: that's how i call the dialog of sms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Iw6r.png)

Edit2: Resolved, there was a problem in my code.

Comment: Any log error shown in Android Studio? please help to attach here

Comment: @PutraNugraha there're no log, the app doesnt crashed, just restarts, same behavior when i click on push notification

Comment: Post the code as text.